# Stream closed EOF for pod in kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am deploying django-react web app on kubernetes I have created the pod for backend its created fine and have status running but I have followed the same steps for the frontend but the pods is not cretaed successfully. Its status changes to `CrashLoopBackOff` right after `Completed` when I check its logs it showing this error  "Stream closed EOF for default/frontend-deployment-56948f4cd4-nsfqx (frontend)".
I am using microk8s and have pushed frontend image to microk8s default docker registry.

frontend.Dockerfile

```
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app/frontend

COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
```

frontend-deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name : frontend-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: frontend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend
          image: localhost:32000/frontend:latest
          command: ["npm", "start"]
          ports:
          - containerPort: 3000
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mentioned that you followed the same steps, could you attach the list of that steps? What version of kubernetes did you use and how did you set up your cluster? Could you also attach logs?